# How to write into host mounted folder from docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a small project running as a docker container to backup my MongoDB data. the backup data is suppose to save in docker host machine. So I'm using `volume` in the `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo_backup:
    container_name: mongo_backup
    build: .
    command: python3 app.py
    volumes:
      - ./backups:/backups
```

When I run this code, a folder named `backups` gets created in the project folder in host machine.

```
if not os.path.exists('./backups/'):
    os.mkdir('./backups/')
```

But when I try to create another folder inside the `./backups/` folder, nothing happens with no errors.

```
if not os.path.exists('./backups/another-folder'):
    os.mkdir('./backups/another-folder')
```

The second folder gets created inside the docker container but nothing happens inside the host machine.

I've set the full access for the entire project folder in case the problem is related to write permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 address/to/project/
```

But it didn't help.

I need to create different folders in the first folder, so I can't add them all as `volume`s. I know I'm missing something. I just don't know what!

This is my `Dockerfile` just in case:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app

COPY src/requirements.txt /app
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY ./src /app
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to map your volumes like this:

```
- ./backups:/app/backups
```

because your working directory is `/app`

here `./backups/another-folder` you are using relative path but you are inside of `/app` so your full path will be `/app/backups/another-folder`